# How to factorise a polynomial in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$

Tags: number-theory

I previously asked a question: [How is $x^2 + x + 1$ reducible in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356968/how-is-x2-x-1-reducible-in-mathbbz-3x), and I got told there that you could factorise $x^2 + x + 1 = (x + 2)(x+2) = (x-1)(x-1)$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ and I understand why.

What I want to know is:

- If I am given a polynomial, lets say $x^2 + x + 1$, what sort of stuff am I looking for to factorise it?
- Does this change is it is a polynomial of a higher order (say something like $x^4 - 1$ (that's the question I have to solve, please don't give an answer for it).
- As the ring is $\mathbb{Z}_p[x]$, do I only look for the $x$ coefficiant to be $\mod p$ or do I look at all coefficiants?
- Will there be a finite number of solutions?
- Is there a method to factorise (i,e quadratic formula) or do I just have to notice the form of the polynomial?

EDIT: In my example, if I want to factorise $x^2 + x + 1$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$, do I want to find polynomials where I have $[1]x^2 + [1]x + [1]$ where the $[a]$ is the equivalence relation (if thats the right word?) $a \mod p$, so in this case it would be $1 \mod 3$?

Comment: The fact that $x^2 + x + 1 = (x + 2)(x + 2)$ in your ring means that $x = -2 = 1$ is a root of the polynomial $x^2 + x + 1$. And indeed, $1^2 + 1^1 + 1 = 3 \equiv 0$, so $x^2 + x + 1$ is divisible by $(x - 1) = (x + 2)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quadratic polynomials can be factored by using the quadratic formula to find their roots (except in characteristic 2, where things are trickier).

Cubic polynomials can be factored by using the cubic formula to find their roots (except in characteristic 2 or 3, where things are trickier). Of course, just like in the rationals, this is painful (albeit less so, IMO). Many times you can identify a root, though, in which case you can factor out the linear factor.

For some special polynomials, identifying the roots (in the algebraic closure) as being of a special form can be very useful if you can relate them to structural things like norms or traces or roots of unity.

There are general methods to factor. One of the main steps is to use the fact that the roots of $ x^q - x$ are all of the elements of $\mathbf{F}_q$. So, for example, you can find the product of all distinct linear factors of a polynomial $f(x)$ over $\mathbf{F}_p$ by computing

$$ \gcd(x^p - x, f(x)) $$

This is useful, because one can efficiently compute modular exponentiation

$$ x^p \pmod{f(x)} $$

to get a gigantic short-cut on the first step of the Euclidean algorithm.

Similarly, the product of all quadratic *and* linear factors is given by

$$ \gcd(x^{p^2} - x, f(x)) $$

(because the roots of an irreducible quadratic over $\mathbf{F}_p$ are elements of $\mathbf{F}_{p^2}$)

Doing these calculations is called "distinct-degree factorization". The next step in a typical general factorization algorithm is "equal-degree factorization".

Comment: Ok, so looking at my quartic, I can split it into two quadratics: $x^4 - 1 = (x^2 + 1)(x^2 - 1) = (x^2 + 1)(x + 1)(x - 1)$. So from here, we see that one root is $x = -1 = 4$ and another is $x = 1$. I can then do $(x^2 + 1) = (x^2 - 4) = (x - 2)(x + 2)$. And so I have factorised $x^4 - 1 = (x + 1)(x - 1)(x + 2)(x - 2)$?

Comment: That looks like the right answer for factoring $x^4 - 1$ over $\mathbf{F}_5$ (because in that field, $+1 = -4$). Other approaches are to note that $x \cdot (x^4 - 1) = x^5 - x$, whose roots are everything in $\mathbf{F}_5$, and noting the roots of $x^4 - 1$ are the fourth roots of unity, and using our knowledge that units of $F_{5^n}$ form a cyclic group of order $5^n - 1$, we should note that they all must be in $\mathbf{F}_5$, and thus we just have to work out what the elements of order 4 are. (All of them, since it's a cyclic group of order $4$).

Answer (score 1):

Barring some really nasty examples, I would just look for zeroes and pull those off in a factorization. Note that multiplication mod $p$ is well defined, so you can factorize in $\mathbb{Z}$ and then reduce if that is what makes you happy. There will be a finite number of results, since a polynomial over a integral domain of degree $n$ can only have at most $n$ roots (good idea to try to prove this [try induction]).

Comment: What do you mean "look for zeroes"? If you want to use an example, you can use that $x^2 + x + 1$ example because I've already got answers to that in my previous question. Also, so if I had to factorise a cubic, I would only get $3$ things I can factorise it into?

Comment: At most 3 things. I didn't want to give too much into actually identifying roots, especially since your homework probably wouldn't expect you to know that. Guess and check is probably good enough for small cases.

Comment: To “look for zeroes” of $x^2+x+1$ in characteristic three, you just plug in $0$, $1$, and $2$ to the polynomial and see whether the result is ever zero.

Comment: @Lubin What does that do then? If I simply plug in $1$, I get $1^2 + 1 + 1 = 3 \equiv 0 \mod 3$, so $1$ is a root. But plugging in $2 = 7 \equiv 1 \mod 3$. How does this then help?